# Tutorial on how to make a trade on the Bisq Decentralized Exchange using Monero to Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin, p2p-exchange, trustless-trading, otc-trading, bisq

With the growing adoption of the Bisq exchange, is there an easy to follow tutorial on how to trade Monero to Bitcoin using the Bisq Decentralized Exchange? How does it work exactly? Is there a monero address you deposit your coins to inside the Bisq applicatoin? And do you have to leave your computer on to make a trade as its a P2P (peer to peer) trade?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfA55mHwMl4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [guide](http://moneroguide.com/2018/11/06/how-to-exchange-monero-using-bisq) to understand how it all works.

BTW: Not only has the computer to be turned on, but the trader also has to be online